# Youtube Video Embed iframe shows the wrong video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

I am making a website and I have to show a video on its homepage. The video exists on youtube and I need to embed it on my website.

```html
<html>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/spPdelVEs_k?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</html>
```

Unfortunately my webpage shows a completely different video. It shows this one.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sNL0T93ItM

Does the URL convert to something different? Help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just need to clear the cookies on your browser and then it should load fine for you.

This is the video your code goes to:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spPdelVEs_k
```